# Getting name of parent shell script

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I am on UBUNTU 12.04.

I have a shell script that logs the output of a certain processes. The process being logged changes depending on the parent shell script that called the logging script. I would like to write the output of this logging to a file on disk, but am having trouble naming the file.

I would love to name it according to the parent script's own name. Unfortunately I have absolutely no idea how to get that name from script. I imagine that the best way to do that would be to extract the parent PID (`$PPID`), and then use that to find the script name, but I also don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of jumping through hoops to do this, just have the parent open the log on say FD4. Then whenever you need to log, just write to FD4.

```
# parent script
exec 4>> parent.log

# child script
echo "Log me!" >&4
```

Comment: Thanks! Much easier than the solution I was devising!

Comment: +1 but would be even better with the child call and FD closing.